# how to make viber and whats app call in iOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp, viber

I want to make viber and whatsapp call and message within my iOS app. I use `@"viber://calls"` and `@"viber://chats"` and for whats app `@"whatsapp://send?text="` and `@"whatsapp://app"`. But this is just opening viber and whats app how can I open a chat window for the specific number directly and make a call directly? And how to handle when the number not saved in the contact?

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: To move to specific chat screen you need `ABID` for that compare with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266825/how-to-move-user-on-specific-contacts-chat-screen-in-whatsapp-from-our-app

Comment: Thanks what about the Viber?